# Pass in variable to tag django

Tags: django

is there a way to pass in a variable in a tag in django templating?

For example, `<a href="{% url '{{ url_path }}' %}">Click here</a>`, as you can see, I want to pass the url_path variable into the url tag, but when I do this, django treats `{{ url_path }}` as the string itself, not the variable url_path.  Is there a way to pass in that variable in the url tag?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply pass a variable without using quotes, and without using curly brackets (`{{ … }}`):

```
<a href="{% url url_path %}">Click here</a>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that is in the logic already, how did I not think of that.  Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: What if I need to append a string like '/abc' to url_path, then pass '{{url_path}}/abc' to url tag?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use quotes, by using quotes Django thinks you want to pass the template page directly.